# Entity Framework Core 7 : this MySQL connection is already in use

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project where I am going to use MySql I've settled on using EF Core with the package `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` - getting data is fine and all.

My problem is, when I try to use the function `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` from the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`; I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use

The full stack trace will be in the code block below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use. See https://fl.vu/mysql-conn-reuse
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.StartQuerying(ICancellableCommand command) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 283
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 51
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 344
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 278
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Load[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.Load(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinderCollectionLoaderAdapter.Load(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.CollectionEntry.Load()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.LazyLoader.Load(Object entity, String navigationName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies.Internal.LazyLoadingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.PersonProxy.get_Connections()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I've tried running eager loading also, while using the "Include(obj => obj.Connections)" without any luck, the following query is the one that is generated by EF Core

```
SELECT `p`.`ID`, `p`.`Age`, `p`.`Created`, `p`.`Deleted`, `p`.`Firstname`, `p`.`Lastname`, `p`.`Updated`, `p`.`Username`
      FROM `People` AS `p`
```

I tried using lazy loading using the `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` in both the context and `Program.cs` without any luck.

I've also tried using eager loading with the success of getting my people data, but not the underlying connections data

I've tried using the following code.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetPeople")]
        public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> result = _context.People;

            return result;

        }
```

Comment: Please post the actual Linq query you are running when you encounter the error. This looks like an un-awaited `async` issue.

Comment: @StevePy I've updated the post with the code i am using to call the context

Comment: @KristianB.Kuhrt another problem with this code is that it delays the execution of the query until the *serializer* tries to iterate the results. Simply assigning a query or a DbSet to an `IEnumerable<>` variable won't execute any queries. When serialization occurs the query will run in a *blocking* manner. Change the method to `async Task<List<Person>>` and use `var people=await _context.People.ToListAsync(); return people;` if you want to return all `Person` records. If you don't want to use List, use `IList` at least. It's easier to serialize stuff when you know how many objects there are

Comment: As for `UseLazyLoadingProxies`, there's no reason to do that in an API response. You *are* returning all objects, so it doesn't make much sense to use lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do not want to do it this way:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetPeople")]
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
{
     IEnumerable<Person> result = _context.People;

     return result;

}
```

Lazy loading or otherwise. The major issue with this is that your controller would be attempting to send back a `DbSet<Person>`. The simplest alternative would be to use:

```
IEnumerable<Person> result = _context.People.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Which would first read the People into memory then serialize the `List` to go back, however again you may run foul of lazy loading. We use AsNoTracking() as we don't need EF to be tracking any entities read this way, they should be treated as detached when leaving the scope of the DbContext. While EF does support operations to work with detached entities, I strongly recommend avoiding them as they lead to more problems and complexity.

My overall advice when it comes to EF and MVC is *do not* pass entities back and forth between controller and views. Use a view model which contains only the data that the view will need. For instance a Person may have several related entities that you might want some details from in this case, but quite possibly others that don't need to, or want to include. Create a simple PersonSummaryViewModel for the fields from Person and any other related details that you want to display, along with the PersonId in case you want to later do something with a selected Person, then use `Select` to project data from the entities to the view model. In this way you both avoid any pitfalls from performance and exceptions around lazy loading, and streamline queries to pull back only what is needed:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetPeople")]
public IEnumerable<PersonSummaryViewModel> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<PersonSummaryViewModel> result = _context.People
        .Select(x => new PersonSummaryViewModel
        {
            PersonId = x.PersonId,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            // etc.
        }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

If a person has an Address entity reference and you want to return that data, you can do it with an AddressViewModel:

```
            Address = x.Address.Select(a => new AddressViewModel
            {
                 // populate address fields.
            }),
```

Or you can flatten info, such as if you only need the Address's City:

```
            City = x.Address.City,
```

EF can build the query to pull back the details from related data provided you follow basic rules that EF can translate down to SQL. If you need to do something with a PersonSummaryViewModel or other ViewModel coming back from a view such as a Form POST, use the ID to load the entity, then copy the expected values from your view model(s) into the loaded entity(ies). Fetching entities by ID is fast, and provides an added validation opportunity to help ensure that the data passed in is still valid.